# 'Region format' & 'Language' inside iPhone settings app for Netherlands

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, regions

What should I select as 'Region format' & 'Language' inside iPhone settings app for Netherlands country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
 Region Format = Dutch

 Language = Nederlands
```